# Ajuda com programa simples de função e soma

Tags: python, algoritmo

Srs,

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte exercício:

> Exercício 2: Escreva uma função em Python, chamada soma_n, que recebe um número inteiro, n,  e
>   calcula a soma 1 + 2 + … + n, se n > 0, ou
>   -1 + -2 + … + -n, se n < 0. Se n = 0, a soma é zero.
>
> A sua função deve verificar se o argumento que recebe é um número
>   inteiro, através da função isinstance(n, int), sendo n o argumento
>   recebido. Em caso contrário a função deverá gerar um erro do tipo
>   ValueError, através da instrução raise ValueError('soma_n: O limite
>   tem de ser um inteiro.’). Por exemplo,
>
> > > > soma_n(3) 6
> > > >         soma_n(-3)
> > > >         -6
> > > >         soma_n(0) 0
> > > >         soma_n('anc') Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >                                         … builtins.ValueError: soma_n: O limite tem de ser um inteiro.

Não percebo o que deve ser feito para adaptar a função isinstance(n, int) ao meu código que é o seguinte:

```
def soma_n (n):

    soma = 0

    while (n != 0):
        if n > 0:
            soma = soma + n
            n = n - 1

        else:
            soma = soma + n
            n = n + 1          
    return (soma)
```

Não percebo esta função isinstance, poderiam me ajudar como utiliza-la junto ao meu código?

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2):

Basta você adicionar o `isinstance(n, int)` na primeira linha da sua função. O `isinstance` verifica se o valor é uma instância de um tipo específico e devolve um valor booleano. Logo você pode usar uma condicional onde, caso o valor `n` não seja um número inteiro, será lançado um erro:

```
def soma_n(n):
    if not isinstance(n,int):
        raise TypeError('Passe para o parâmetro "n" um número inteiro.')
    soma = 0

    while n != 0:
        if n > 0:
            soma += n
            n += -1

        else:
            soma += n
            n += 1         
    return soma
```

Detalhe: Esse tipo de erro deve ser um `TypeError`. Se você quisesse por exemplo que o valor não fosse 10, você poderia utilizar o `ValueError`, porém estamos falando de tipos de valores. Como você quer que o valor passado no parâmetro seja somente um `int` e não uma `str`, `bool` ou `float`, você deve lançar um `TypeError`